# Setting up a GCP service account as the owner of powerbi dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, powerbi, service-accounts

I want to change the ownership of a Power BI dataset from my email to a GCP service account. This way, if the refresh is not successful, more people can take action to do a manual refresh ( or any other cases, I think one person being the owner of a dataset really doesn't make sense). I've searched a lot but haven't found an answer yet. Anyone knows if it's doable and how to do that?

Comment: You know, that refresh notifications can be sent not only to the owner of the dataset, but also to other people (and groups), right? https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sending-refresh-notifications-to-others/

Comment: That doesn't matter, only the owner can do a manual refresh incase that's needed and that's the main reason we wanted to have the capability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a talk with the Microsoft team and they told me regarding our use case, we can not use service accounts. The only use cases SAs can be used is   for [embedded scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app?tabs=customers)(embed for org or customers) and doesn't serve the purpose of your scenario. The only option that was given to us was to create a shared MS account with the pbi license so that all the people on-call on the DevOps team would be able to use to refresh the datasets (or investigate when needed)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Google SA directly, you need to  download the [JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#iam-service-account-keys-create-console) for the Service Account.

With [Workload Identity with Azure](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#prepare), you will need to use Azure AD to auth your PowerBI users on the Azure MS365 App.
You can review the document To configure the use of workload identity federation, configure a workload identity pool and a workload identity pool provider in your project.